# Unity, как задать инициализацию объекта в локальных координатах?

Tags: unity3d, vector3

Которую минуту пытаюсь понять как сделать так, чтобы объект (префаб) появлялся в условной "арке" в рандомных координатах, всё работает хорошо, но только до того момента когда я пытаюсь повернуть арку. Как я понял к локальным  координатам "арки" прибавляются глобальные, или как? я слишком глуп чтобы понять что тут не так.

```
Vector3 pos = new Vector3(Random.Range(-9.5f, 9.5f), Random.Range(-3.5f, 3.5f));
Instantiate(planeObj, gameObject.transform.position + pos,gameObject.transform.rotation);
```

Comment: Там перегрузка есть чтобы инстанцировать в дочернем обьекте. (GameObject pref, Transform parent)

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Foo : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private Vector3 _spawnScatter = new Vector2(19, 7, 0);
    [SerializeField] private GameObject _template;

    public void Spawn ()
    {
        Transform parent = transform;
        Transform target = Instantiate(_template, parent).transform;
        target.localPosition = GetScatterPosition(_spawnScatter);
    }

    private Vector3 GetScatterPosition (Vector3 _scatter)
    {
        return new Vector3(GetScatterValue(_scatter.x), GetScatterValue(_scatter.y), GetScatterValue(_scatter.z));
    }

    private float GetScatterValue (float range) => return Random.Range(-range, range)*0.5f;
}
```